# How to Scraping Booking comments with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, booking.com-api

I want to print all comments of specific hotel.

I use this code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.booking.com/reviews/co/hotel/ibis-bogota-museo.es.html?page=1;r_lang=all;rows=75'
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
    }
)

f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read().decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
reviews = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "review_item clearfix "})
for review in reviews:
    print(review.find("div", {"class": "review_item_header_content"}).text)
```

But nothing print!

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 0):

import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url='https://www.booking.com/reviews/co/hotel/ibis-bogota-museo.es.html?page=1;r_lang=all;rows=75'

response2 = requests.get(url)

if response2.ok is True:

```
selector = Selector(text=response2.content)
print(selector.xpath("//div[@class='review_item_header_content_container']").get())
```